# how to use fest for android

Tags: android, unit-testing, robolectric, fest

I am trying to use FEST with an android app testing

I want to check if some views in the activity got created and initialized correctly

```
@Test
    public void testSplashScreenActivity() throws Exception{
        SplashScreenActivity activity = Robolectric.buildActivity(SplashScreenActivity.class).create().start().resume().get();

//here i want to write fest assertions 
    }
```

however, when i `assertThat(activity.welcomeText)`..... nothing is allowed after this line?

i wrote import static org.fest.assertions.api.ANDROID.assertThat;
in my imports, yet the api doesnt seem to be available

what to do to make my test project give me the api i need ?

Comment: Do you added FEST dependency to project?

Comment: yes i did add fest dependency to project

Comment: My English is terrible. Take a look to http://square.github.io/fest-android/

Comment: Compilation requires Android 4.1 or newer. -i found last line in the website you gave me, does this mean that if my project's minSDK version is less than Android 4.1 it will not work ?

Comment: I think this is about target sdk. But I'm not sure